# Show that $Y_n $ converges in distribution when suitably normalized

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

> Define $$Y_n = \frac{X_1 +X_2 + \cdots X_n}{X_1^2 +X^2_2 + \cdots X^2_n}\,,$$ where $X_1 ,X_2 , \dots$ are iid $U(-1,1)$.
>
> Show that $Y_n$ when suitably normalized, converges in distribution to some distribution.

$\textbf{My Take:}$ Let $Z_n=X_1 +X_2 + \dots X_n$ and $W_n=X_1^2 +X_2^2 + \dots X_n^2$

By CLT, $\sqrt{n}(\frac
{Z_n}{n} - E(X_1)) = \sqrt{n}(\frac{Z_n}{n})\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}N(0, 1/3)$ since $E(X_1) = 0$ and $\sigma^2_X = 1/3$.

Similarly, $\sqrt{n}(\frac {W_n}{n} - E(X^2_1)) = \sqrt{n}(\frac{W_n}{n} - 1/3)\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}N(1/3, 4/45)$, since $E(X^2_1) = 1/3$ and $\sigma^2_X = 4/45$.

Thus, $Y_n = \frac{N(0,1/3)}{N(1/3,4/45)}$ I am stuck-in here. I don't know how to simplify this.

$\textbf{Textbook solution:}$ The numerator is $N(0,1/3)$ and the denominator is $1/3$ and so $\sqrt{n}Y_n = \frac{\sqrt{n} Z_n/n}{W_n/n}\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} \frac{N(0,1/3)}{1/3} = 3N(0,1/3) = N(0,3)$

$\textbf{Questions}$

1. Why is my approach wrong?
2. If my approach is not wrong, how do I simplify the ratio of two distributions?
3. From the textbook solution, what is the algebra from $3N(0,1/3)$ to $N(0,3)$ i.e. the trick.

Comment: For part 3, if you have $N(\mu ,\sigma)$ then $3N(\mu,\sigma) = N(\mu,3\sigma)$ (equality in distribution) because standard deviation is multiplicative.

Comment: The textbook uses Slutsky's theorem directly. And if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $aX\sim N(a\mu,a^2\sigma^2)$ in general for any constant $a$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom. Slutsky's theorem shows addition, subtraction, multiplication and division of two sequences of random variables but does not show what you have given, probable it has another name but not slutsky's theorem. Let me know if you have the correct name of your theorem.

Comment: @rubikscube09. What is the name of this theorem or lemma

Comment: If you are referring to the fact about normal distribution, then it is a very special case of its reproductive property. You can probably prove it easily.

Comment: There is no need to "suitably normalize."  By the law of large numbers it holds that $Y_n\rightarrow 0$ with probability 1 (just multiply numerator and denominator by $1/n$).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't quite work because $Z_n$ and $W_n$ are not independent sequences of random variables. You can instead use the Law of Large Numbers to show that $W_n/n \rightarrow 1/3$ in probability. Finally invoke [Slutsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) as stated in the comments.